# How do I save all the pages of a PDDocument in seperate .pdf files?

Tags: java, pdfbox

I want to save all the pages of a PDDocument in a seperate pdf file.
I programmed it like this:

```
int numberOfPages = pdDocument.getNumberOfPages();
for (int i = 0; i < numberOfPages; i++) {
    PDDocument pageDocument = new PDDocument();
    PDPage page = pdDocument.getPage(i);
    pageDocument.add(page);
    pageDocument.save("c:\temp\page" + (i+1));
}
```

Is this the correct way to do it? Do I have to create each time a new PDDocument and add the page to it or is there a better way to save the pages of a PDDocument individually?

To be more clear:
I want to save each page in a PDDocument in separate pdfs.
So, if I have a PDDocument with 25 pages in it, I want to save each page in a separate pdf.
Like this:
-page1.pdf
-page2.pdf
-page3.pdf
...
-page25.pdf

I'm just wondering if I have to make a new PDDocument object for each page to save it to a pdf.

Comment: This is contradictional. Do you want to save all pages in a PDDocument or all pages in (different) PDDocuments ?

Answer (score 1):

Use splitter to split the PDDocument into seperate PDDocuments, simple example can be

```
Splitter splitter = new Splitter();
splitter.setStartPage(start); //page to start from
splitter.setEndPage(end); //page to end at
List<PDDocument> splittedItems = splitter.split(doc); //doc is original document
for(int index = 0; index < splittedItem.length(); index++){
    splittedItem[index].save("destination to save");
}
```

In your case it would be,

```
  int numberOfPages = pdDocument.getNumberOfPages();
  Splitter splitter = new Splitter();
  splitter.setStartPage(1);
  splitter.setEndPage(numberOfPages); //page to end at
  List<PDDocument> splittedItems = splitter.split(pdDocument); 
    for(int index = 0; index < splittedItem.length(); index++){
        splittedItem[index].save("c:\temp\page" + (index+1));
    }
```

For more information you can check out documentation
https://pdfbox.apache.org/docs/2.0.3/javadocs/org/apache/pdfbox/multipdf/Splitter.html

Answer (score 0):

Please try (untested):

```
PDDocument pageDocument = new PDDocument();
for (int i = 0; i < pdDocument.getNumberOfPages(); i++) {
    pageDocument.add(pdDocument.getPage(i));
}
pageDocument.save("c:\temp\page");
```

It should be possible to add multiple pages to a PDDocument.

Comment: This does not answer the question. If this works, wouldn't it simply copy the document instead of splitting it per page?

Comment: Yes, but didn't you want to save all pages in one file? Sorry, then I don't know what you mean.